# Exclude urls from service-worker using webpack offline-plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, service-worker, react-boilerplate

i’m currently setting up 2 apps on the same domain using AWS Cloudfront to manage routes between the apps. One of the 2 apps is a React app, based on React-Boilerplate and using offline-plugin to setup service workers. By default,  routes of the react app are whitelisted in Cloudfront and the fallback routes are the routes of the other app (/blog for example).

The problem comes from the service workers of the React app which return the default 404 when calling a route of the other app.

I guess my url that should redirect to the other app, based on Cloudfront redirect, (for instance /blog which is a wordpress) is intercepted by the service worker and then return a 404 from the main app.

I've tried some options provided by webpack offline-plugin but my understanding of service-workers is not optimal... 
I've tried playing with `responseStrategy`, `excludes`, ServiceWorkers `cacheName` but no success.

```
new OfflinePlugin({
      publicPath: '/',
      appShell: '/',
      excludes: ['.htaccess'],
      caches: {
        main: [':rest:'],
        additional: ['*.chunk.js'],
      },
      safeToUseOptionalCaches: true,
    }),
```

Comment: Did you find a way at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Use it in your

> app.js

```
import * as serviceWorker from 'utils/serviceWorker';

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

> utils/serviceWorker.js

```
// In production, we register a service worker to serve assets from local cache.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on the "N+1" visit to a page, since previously
// cached resources are updated in the background.


// This link also includes instructions on opting out of this behavior.

const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/,
    ),
);

export function register(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
              'worker. To learn more, visit ',
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not local host. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the old content will have been purged and
              // the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
              // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is
              // available; please refresh." message in your web app.
              console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        response.headers.get('content-type').indexOf('javascript') === -1
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.',
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The problem can be fixed by using a combination of [cacheMaps](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin/blob/master/docs/cache-maps.md) and **FALLBACK** options

Example:

```
...
cacheMaps: [{
    match: function(url) {
        if (url.pathname.indexOf('/blog') === 0) {
               return new URL('/blog', location);
        }
            
        return new URL('/', location);
     },
     requestTypes: ['navigate']
}],

FALLBACK: {
    '/blog': '/blog', 
},
...
```

So, the service worker tries to match /blog to the hash he has in the list. If not found, it does look up in a FALLBACK and in case of match, redirects to the path you provided. It can be relative path as in example above or full external url like here:

```
...
FALLBACK: {
    '/blog': 'https:/example.com/blog', 
},
...
```